# Python pandas integer precision loss through implicit conversion

Tags: python, pandas

I am working with a lot of different csv files read in as pandas dataframes and then extract interesting indizes and data from them and collect it in a new dataframe, which I build line by line and then save. Each line represents the information from one file.

The original dataframes are indexed on millisecond precision epoch times. Although the times are unnecessarily precise, I cannot change anything about it.

```
>>> df.index
Int64Index([1382441313687, 1382441314687, 1382441315687, 1382441316687,
        1382441317687, 1382441318687, 1382441319687, 1382441320687,
        1382441321687, 1382441322687,
        ...
        1382445583687, 1382445584687, 1382445585687, 1382445586687,
        1382445587687, 1382445588687, 1382445589687, 1382445590687,
        1382445591687, 1382445592687],
       dtype='int64', name=u'time', length=4280)
```

I build the new dataframe by building a list of interesting values and creating a series out of it, which I then append to the dataframe.

```
columns = ['Start time', 'End time']
summary = pd.DataFrame(columns=columns)
for i, df in enumerate(long_list_of_dfs):
     start_time = df.index[0]
     end_time = df.index[-1]
     data = [start_time, end_time]
     new_line = pd.Series({key:val for key, val in zip(columns, data)})
     summary = summary.append(new_line)
summary.to_csv(out_dir)
```

I use the saved indizes from the summary to quickly index interesting points in the original dataframes. However, while building the new dataframe, some precision gets lost, and I end up with the following:

```
>>> for line in open(out_dir):
...     print(line)
,Start time,End time
0,1.38244131369e+12,138244559269e+12
```

When reading in this summary again, I cannot use these values to index the original dataframes anymore, as it results in a KeyError. This does not happen when building the dataframe directly:

```
>>> summary2 = pd.DataFrame({'Start time':[1382441313687], 'End time':[1382445592687]})
>>> summary2
        End time     Start time
0  1382445592687  1382441313687
>>> summary2.to_csv(out_dir)
>>> for line in open(out_dir):
...     print(line)
,Start time,End time
0,1382441313687,1382445592687
```

Does anyone know why this conversion happens? I know I could specify datatypes, but I have a lot of columns with different datatypes and would rather save the hassle. I feel it would also be more intuitive if the values would remain in the original formatting.

**EDIT**
I want to emphasize that I build the Dataframe inside a for loop because I have many data points of interest I want to add per each line. Also, the amount of original dataframes is rather high (~90.000 files @ 20MB each), so I want to open each file only once.

The code above is just a working example to show that despite the data being integer, the last two digits get rounded off, presumably in the append line. The `new_line` Series still has the data in its original format, up to the last two digits.

Below is is the output of summary.info() for the first 10 lines. As you can see, there are columns that contain NaNs, but also some that don't. I would expect the columns without NaNs to retain their integer format.

```
>>> summary.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 88158 entries, 0 to 88157
Data columns (total 46 columns):
Date added            88158 non-null object
Filename              88158 non-null object
ACID                  88158 non-null int64
FLID                  88158 non-null int64
Flag                  88158 non-null object
L ESN                 86986 non-null float64
R ESN                 86986 non-null float64
Start time            88158 non-null float64
End time              88158 non-null float64
Total duration        88158 non-null float64
```

**EDIT2**
Here is another short example to show my problem when building a dataframe line by line with long integers.

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['a', 'b'])
>>> df.loc[len(df.index)] = [1382441313687, 1382441314687]
>>> df
              a             b
0  1.382441e+12  1.382441e+12
>>> df.loc[0, 'a']
1382441313687.0 # Correct data!
>>> df.to_csv(out_dir)
>>> for line in open(out_dir):
...     print(line)    
,a,b
0,1.38244131369e+12,1.38244131469e+12 # Not correct! 1382441313690 != 1382441313687
```

Comment: can you give `summary.info()` Possibly there are some `NaN`s there and these columns gets converted to float

Comment: I added the first ten lines of `summary.info()` to the question. As you can see, there are lines that get converted to float despite have no null values.

Comment: Why don't you convert the `Start time` etc columns to `Timestamp`, then there will be no loss of precision

Comment: This is a solution I would consider if there is no better solution. I would rather use epoch times, however.

Comment: What is wrong with my Summary generator method? instead of `s = [df[k].mean() for k in columns]` you can summarize it the way you want it without problem

Comment: `1382441313687.0 # Correct data!` is not correct, it got converted to a `float`, which then gets concatenated when converting to `csv`

Comment: If the problem stems from the float conversion, this is indeed not correct data. It just had the correct value. Could you eloborate on your Summary generator how you would dump its output to a csv file? This is what I want to end up with.

Comment: Thank you both for your input. I've decided to go with the generator function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because you append a `Series`, which has one `dtype`, so if it contains 1 `float`, the others get cast to `float` too.

I only managed to reproduce your problem by slightly adapting your code

## Sample data generation

```
columns = ['sample_data']
columns2 = ['Start time', 'End time'] + columns
long_list_of_dfs = [pd.DataFrame(index=[i**2 + j for j in range(i)], columns=columns, data=[j**2 for j in range(i)]) for i in range(5, 15)]
```

## Adapted original code

```
summary2 = pd.DataFrame(columns=columns2)
for i, df in enumerate(long_list_of_dfs):
    start_time = df.index[0]
    end_time = df.index[-1]
    data = [df[k].mean() for k in columns]
    new_line = pd.Series({key:val for key, val in zip(columns2, [start_time, end_time] + data)}, name=i)
    summary2 = summary.append(new_line)
summary2.info()
```

> result:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 11 entries, 0 to 9
Data columns (total 3 columns):
Start time     11 non-null float64
End time       11 non-null float64
sample_data    11 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(3)
memory usage: 352.0 bytes
```

> new_line

```
End time       209.0
Start time     196.0
sample_data     58.5
Name: 9, dtype: float64
```

so the conversion happens before the appending

## Summary generator

A way to prevent this is not making a `Series` for every original `DataFrame`, but using a generator like this.
This can be any method you use to generate the summary you need

```
def get_summary_data(long_list_of_dfs, columns):
    for df in long_list_of_dfs:
        s = [df[k].mean() for k in columns]
        # print(df.index[0], df.index[-1], *s)
        yield (df.index[0], df.index[-1], *s)
```

and then concatenating

```
summary = pd.DataFrame(data=get_summary_data(long_list_of_dfs, columns), columns=columns2)
```

> result

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 10 entries, 0 to 9
Data columns (total 3 columns):
Start time     10 non-null int64
End time       10 non-null int64
sample_data    10 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(1), int64(2)
memory usage: 320.0 bytes
```

> Summary:

```
    Start time  End time    sample_data
0   25  29  6.000000
1   36  41  9.166667
2   49  55  13.000000
3   64  71  17.500000
4   81  89  22.666667
5   100     109     28.500000
6   121     131     35.000000
7   144     155     42.166667
8   169     181     50.000000
9   196     209     58.500000
```

This `DataFrame` can be exported using `to_csv()`

Comment: A Series can have multiple datatypes as far as I am aware, e.g. `S = pd.Series({'a':10, 'b':2.5, 'c':'s'})`. The problem is not the datatype itself, but the truncation of very long numbers when writing the file (which might be due to the dtype however, I do not know). I'll add another short example to the question to clarify.

Comment: then why does the `iterrows` [documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html#pandas.DataFrame.iterrows) specifically mention this, and was I able to reproduce this behaviour with the adapted original code

Comment: and you example series has dtype `object`, so that preserves ints and floats, but `pd.Series({'a':10, 'b':2.5, 'c':5.3})` is of dtype `float64`

Comment: You are correct, that is probably because of the string then. I switched my code to not include a Series and still have the problem. Please see my new example in EDIT2, where there is no float in the dataframe at all and I do not use Series or df.append(), yet all values get cast to it anyway.

Comment: I seem to have forgotten the line actually concatenating the data. Repaired it

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tracked down where your loss of precision occurred, but

```
summary = pd.DataFrame([(df.index[0], df.index[-1]) for df in long_list_of_dfs],
                       columns=['Start Time', 'End Time'])
```

works without loss when I try it, and matches your summary2.

**Edit: Just saw the main post edits.**

It looks like selecting single values with `.loc` converts ints to floats, though this doesn't seem to apply to longer selections. Even with this, though, `np.float64`s are preserved under `df.to_csv(file), pd.read_csv(file)` operations if in a Series of such. The problem seems to come in with the mixed datatypes giving a Series dtype of `object`, which then causes these floats to be treated as their string representation when written to the file, causing the loss of precision.

So avoiding conversion to a pandas object until after you've extracted the values you want from each df into tuples,

```
df_summaries = []
columns = ['Start time', 'End time']  # and any other you wanted here
for df in long_list_of_dfs:
    # build your tuples of desired df info
summary = pd.DataFrame(df_summaries, columns=columns)
```

or constructing a single-row df for each, to should allow proper recognition of datatypes by field, and using `pd.concat` on those (which is much faster than using `.append` for each)

```
df_summaries = []
columns = ['Start time', 'End time']  # and any other you wanted here
for df in long_list_of_dfs:
    # build your summary row dataframes of desired info from full-size dataframes
summary = pd.concat(df_summaries)
```

should resolve your problem.

Note: I cannot reproduce the issue seen in Edit2. Following those steps gets the floats back with full precision for me.

Comment: This is correct, but unfortunately due to the amount of data I do not want to go through each input Dataframe more than once. The loss of precision seems to occur in the `summary = summary.append(new_line)` line.

Comment: @Alarik Not my best moment. Adjusted to only access each df once.