# Python pandas large floats with to_csv

Tags: python, pandas, precision

I am having a [recurring problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44138055/python-pandas-integer-precision-loss-through-implicit-conversion) with saving large numbers in Python to csv. The numbers are millisecond epoch time stamps, which I cannot convert or truncate and have to save in this format. As the columns with the millisecond timestamps also contain some NaN values, pandas casts them automatically to float (see [the documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/gotchas.html) in the Gotchas under "Support for integer NA".

I cannot seem to avoid this behaviour, so my question is, how can I save these numbers as an integer value when using df.to_csv, i.e. with no decimal point or trailing zeros? I have columns with numbers of different floating precision in the same dataframe and I do not want to lose the information there. Using the `float_format` parameter in to_csv seems to apply the same format for ALL float columns in my dataframe.

An example:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1.25, 2.54], 'b':[1424380449437, 1425510731187]})
>>> df['b'].dtype
Out[1]: dtype('int64')
>>> df.loc[2] = np.NaN
>>> df
Out[1]: 
       a             b
0   1.25  1.424380e+12
1   2.54  1.425511e+12
2    NaN           NaN
>>> df['b'].dtype
dtype('float64')
>>> df.to_csv('test.csv')
>>> with open ('test.csv') as f:
...     for line in f:
...         print(line)
,a,b
0,1.25,1.42438044944e+12
1,2.54,1.42551073119e+12
2,,
```

As you can see, I lost the precision of the last two digits of my epoch time stamp.

Comment: You could potentially replace the `nan` values with zero and then convert the column to intergers. `df.b = df.b.fillna(0).astype(int)` or use `-1` to identify the entries in later processing.

Comment: That's a possibility, but a rather clunky workaround. I would prefer to keep the `nan` values as such, because it allows for easy indexing and filtering. Also, any placeholder value I use for the `nan` could potentially occur in the Dataframe naturally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While [`pd.to_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) does not have a parameter to change the format of individual columns, [`pd.to_string`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_string.html) does. It is a little cumbersome and might be a problem for very large DataFrames but you can use it to produce a properly formatted string and then write that string to a file (as suggested in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20003290/print-different-precision-by-column-with-pandas-dataframe-to-csv) to a similar question). `to_string`'s `formatters` parameter takes for example a dictionary of functions to format individual columns. In your case, you could write your own custom formatter for the `"b"` column, leaving the defaults for the other column(s). This formatter might look somewhat like this:

```py
def printInt(b):
    if pd.isnull(b):
        return "NaN"
    else:
        return "{:d}".format(int(b))
```

Now you can use this to produce your string:

```py
df.to_string(formatters={"b": printInt}, na_rep="NaN")
```

which gives:

```
'      a             b\n0  1.25 1424380449437\n1  2.54 1425510731187\n2   NaN           NaN'
```

You can see that there is still the problem that this is not comma separated and `to_string` actually has no parameter to set a custom delimiter, but this can easily be fixed by a regex:

```py
import re
re.sub("[ \t]+(NaN)?", ",",
       df.to_string(formatters={"b": printInt}, na_rep="NaN"))
```

gives:

```
',a,b\n0,1.25,1424380449437\n1,2.54,1425510731187\n2,,'
```

This can now be written into the file:

```py
with open("/tmp/test.csv", "w") as f:
    print(re.sub("[ \t]+(NaN)?", ",",
                 df.to_string(formatters={"b": printInt}, na_rep="NaN")),
          file=f)
```

which results in what you wanted:

```
,a,b  
0,1.25,1424380449437  
1,2.54,1425510731187  
2,,
```

---

If you want to keep the `NaN`'s in the csv-file, you can just change the regex:

```py
with open("/tmp/test.csv", "w") as f:
    print(re.sub("[ \t]+", ",",
                 df.to_string(formatters={"b": printInt}, na_rep="NaN")),
          file=f)
```

will give:

```
,a,b
0,1.25,1424380449437
1,2.54,1425510731187
2,NaN,NaN
```

---

If your DataFrame contained strings with whitespaces before, a robust solution is not as easy. You could insert another character in front of every value, that indicates the start of the next entry. If you have only single whitespaces in all strings you could use another whitespace for example. This would change the code to this:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import re

df = pd.DataFrame({'a a':[1.25, 2.54], 'b':[1424380449437, 1425510731187]})
df.loc[2] = np.NaN

def printInt(b):
    if pd.isnull(b):
        return " NaN"
    else:
        return " {:d}".format(int(b))

def printFloat(a):
    if pd.isnull(a):
        return " NaN"
    else:
        return " {}".format(a)

with open("/tmp/test.csv", "w") as f:
    print(re.sub("[ \t][ \t]+", ",",
                 df.to_string(formatters={"a": printFloat, "b": printInt},
                              na_rep="NaN", col_space=2)),
          file=f)
```

which would give:

```
,a a,b
0,1.25,1424380449437
1,2.54,1425510731187
2,NaN,NaN
```

Comment: I'm sorry the example at the end is not what I wanted, but what I wanted to avoid. So `NaN`s should be represented as such. Also, how can I have the regex not split up my column names that consist of more than one word?

Comment: I updated my answer to allow for whitespaces in column names and to keep the NaN's (I thought you only wanted those to stay in `df`). Does this help?

Comment: I accepted your answer, because it solves my problem, though it remains a horrendous workaround, mostly because I had to specify the formatters for a few dozen columns ;) I chose the single spacing regex matching, as the double spacing would run into trouble with pandas' `to_string` function when column names or cell entries were too long (as it would only leave a single space in the column). Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this could work:

```
pd.set_option('precision',15)
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1.25, 2.54], 'b':[1424380449437, 1425510731187]})
fg = df.applymap(lambda x: str(x))
fg.loc[2] = np.NaN
fg.to_csv('test.csv', na_rep='NaN')
```

Your output should be something like this (I'm on a mac):

[image]

Comment: But in this case you have to change the DataFrames entries to strings before inserting `NaN`'s, isn't it?

Comment: @jotasi yes, otherwise you lose precision. I figured it could be an alternative to yours

Comment: Thank you for your input, but this doesn't work for me - my original dataframe has the NaNs all along, I'm adding them only after in the example to show how the columns get force casted to float.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problems with large numbers, this is the correct way for excel files
df = "\t" + df

Comment: How and where do you add this line of code `df = "\t" + df` ?

Comment: you can added right before the to_csv operation for example:
`df = pd.read_excel(excel_file_path, skiprows=4)
df = df.loc[:, ~df.columns.str.contains('^Unnamed')]
df.dropna(subset = ["Column1"], inplace=True)
df="\t" + df
df.to_csv(r'{file_path}.csv'.format(file_path=os.path.join(DestinationPath, filename)), index=False, header=False)` @tlentali